# Show that $\omega : I \to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $\omega(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$ is a closed map.

Tags: general-topology, closed-map

> Show that $\omega : I \to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $\omega(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$ is a closed map, where $I = [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

What I did so far was note that since $I$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, $A \subseteq I$ is closed in $I$ if and only if $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. So the closed sets of $I$ are of the form $[a, b] \subseteq I$, where $0 \leq a \leq 1$ and $0 \leq b \leq 1$.

I then tried to use the theorem that $f : X \to Y$ is continuous and closed if and only if $f[\overline{A}] = \overline{f[A]}$ for any subset $A \subseteq X$, and the fact that closed sets contain their boundary points.

So I noted that the boundary points of $A = [a, b] \subseteq I$ are $\{a, b\}$, and I tried to show $\text{Bd}(\omega[A]) = \{\omega(a), \omega(b)\}$, and I tried to argue by contradiction but I didn't get anywhere, (and it seems like I'm taking a long route to prove something that shouldn't be too hard to prove)

Is there any easier way to prove that $\omega$ is a closed map? Is there any way that I can complete the proof that $\omega$ is a closed map using my line of reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You can just directly prove that the image of a closed set is closed, using the fact that any closed subset of $I$ is compact.

(Also, it is *not* true that a closed subset of $I$ must be a closed interval!  Closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are much more general than closed intervals.  For instance, you could have a union of two closed intervals, or something much more complicated like a Cantor set.)

Comment: To prove your hint, pick a closed set $A \subseteq I$, and note that $I$ is compact, so $A$ is compact, and $\omega[A]$ is compact in $S^1$ by continuity of $\omega$, and a compact subset of a Haursdoff space ($S^1$) is closed, so $\omega[A]$ is closed in $S^1$

Comment: But now I don't see why any continuous map from a compact space to a Haursdoff space isn't closed, because I haven't used any specific property of $\omega$

Comment: That's correct.  Any continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: To the proposer: Let $X$ be compact.  Then any closed $C\subset X$ is compact........ Let $Y$ be Hausdorff and let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous. For closed $C\subset X ,$  the image $f(C)$ is compact (because $ f(C)$ is the continuous image of the compact set $C$). And  a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is a closed set. So $f(C)$ is closed in $Y.$